# Integration testing framework for rest Kafka and soap services

Tags: citrus-framework

Hi there I would like to build an integration test framework that supports testing soap services mq Kafka and rest services - can someone say if citrus framework would be a better choice ? And some p tutorial to refer at ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Citrus already covers all of those features mentioned so I would suggest to have a look and try before heading to something else or implement it yourself.

The framework is Open Source so you can also contribute to it and enhance where you feel it is necessary.

I often give reference to the samples section where you find running samples of all features you have mentioned.

https://citrusframework.org/samples/